# Selenium Grid showing 4 request waiting for slots to be free

Tags: ios, appium, selenium-grid

I'm facing issue with selenium grid on iOS where my hub is present on window and node on MAC, in mac I have already configured appium and safari browser is getting launched from the appium, also the  connection between hub and node is successfully connected but whenever I try to run selenium script from hub than I receive an error from grid (http://localhost:4444) i.e 4 requests waiting for a slot, see below the grid error

Error on Grid:

> 4 requests waiting for a slot to be free. Capabilities {app:
>   /Users/admin/Library/Develo..., automationName: XCUITest, browserName:
>   safari, deviceName: iPad 6, platform: IOS, platformversion: 12.0,
>   server:CONFIG_UUID: ebedf656-c034-499c-a82f-84a..., udid:
>   78cd2ebbb499e869ffc1eb7b2ff..., xcodeConfigFile:
>   /Users/admin/Desktop/xcode...., xcodeOrgId: XJQAE4L5HQ,
>   xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer} Capabilities {app:
>   /Users/admin/Library/Develo..., automationName: XCUITest, browserName:
>   safari, deviceName: iPad 6, platform: IOS, platformversion: 12.0,
>   server:CONFIG_UUID: ebedf656-c034-499c-a82f-84a..., udid:
>   78cd2ebbb499e869ffc1eb7b2ff..., version: , xcodeConfigFile:
>   /Users/admin/Desktop/xcode...., xcodeOrgId: XJQAE4L5HQ,
>   xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer} Capabilities {app:
>   /Users/admin/Library/Develo..., automationName: XCUITest, browserName:
>   safari, deviceName: iPad 6, platform: IOS, platformversion: 12.0,
>   server:CONFIG_UUID: ebedf656-c034-499c-a82f-84a..., udid:
>   78cd2ebbb499e869ffc1eb7b2ff..., version: , xcodeConfigFile:
>   /Users/admin/Desktop/xcode...., xcodeOrgId: XJQAE4L5HQ,
>   xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer} Capabilities {app:
>   /Users/admin/Library/Develo..., automationName: XCUITest, browserName:
>   safari, deviceName: iPad 6, platform: IOS, platformversion: 12.0,
>   server:CONFIG_UUID: ebedf656-c034-499c-a82f-84a..., udid:
>   78cd2ebbb499e869ffc1eb7b2ff..., version: , xcodeConfigFile:
>   /Users/admin/Desktop/xcode...., xcodeOrgId: XJQAE4L5HQ,
>   xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}